# ganglia vs sensu vs icinga vs nagios

Tags: amazon-web-services, monitoring, nagios, ganglia, sensu

I am looking for a monitoring tool for hosts and services running under AWS. We are not looking for paid solutions, but we would like to run a monitoring server. In our cloud, we will launch and remove services (web servers, queues, etc) and hosts. I wonder what tool is best to monitor hosts and services when they will be added/removed in a daily basis?

I am considering Ganglia, Nagios, Icinga and Sensu. Any other ***not paid*** option is welcome too as long as it can monitor the described scenario.

Comment: If you master on one of any tools in your list, they are the best for you.

Comment: sensu would be my first choice

Answer (score 1):

Personally I'm a Nagios XI fan. But if you really need to keep it completely free, OMD is something you could also consider. OMD stands for Open Monitoring Distribution. It contains several different Nagios frontends and is pretty easy to install. The best web interface it contains is check_mk, which is really good. Please read through this: http://omdistro.org/
As suggested before either one could work for you, as long as you take the time to master it.

Grtz

Willem

Answer (score 0):

I finally solve my problem with Ganglia + grafana + grafana-alerts. It works ok for my problem.